# Nodejs Express get raw content of user uploaded file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Is it possible to get the raw file contents from a user uploaded file in Nodejs Express?

```
app.post('/images', upload.single('image'), async (req, res) => {
  const file = req.file
  ...
```

I realised that the `file` variable in this case is of the type `object` and I am struggling to get the raw data that is inside of it.

More specifically, those files in my case will only be SVG, and I would like to reference some certain tags and data in those files. I have searched around a lot for a solution to this problem, thanks.

**Edit: added form**

```
<form onSubmit={submit}>
    <input onChange={fileSelected} type="file" accept=".svg"></input>
    <input value={description} onChange={e => setDescription(e.target.value)} type="text"></input>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: its in `req.file.buffer`

Comment: Yes I am using multer

Comment: Unfortunately `req.file.buffer` equates `undefined` for me

Comment: can you show your complete form? inc enctype etc

Comment: Sure, I will add it as an edit to the main question

Comment: your missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on the form

Comment: Thanks what does `enctype="multipart/form-data"` do exactly? I also added it to the form and tried out the previous answers, but it didn't seem to make much difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the contents of the file with the `fs` library.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const fsPromises = fs.promises

app.post('/images', upload.single('image'), async (req, res) => {
  const file = req.file
  let fileContent = await fsPromises.readFile(req.file.path, 'utf8')
  console.log(fileContent)
  ...
```

**More information**

[FS API](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)

[Callback, Promise, Async/Await](https://dev.to/tqbit/what-is-the-difference-between-callback-functions-promises-and-async-await-in-javascript-1c2k)

Comment: Trying to reference `req.raw` returns `undefined` for me

Comment: Are there any libraries needed to make this work?

Comment: You just want the contents of the file?

Comment: Exactly only the raw content

Comment: Thanks, now I got the error `Callback must be a function`

Comment: Seems to be `(node:59044)` with traceback
`at maybeCallback (fs.js:129:9)` `at Object.readFile (fs.js:278:14)`

Comment: Are you sure you wrote exactly my answer? You may missed the `.promises` on the require.

Comment: Worked! I did forget to add `.promises`

Comment: Adding `.promises` what does it do? Will it mess up something else possibly?

Comment: It returns a promise instead of a callback so you can use it with the `await` syntax, it could mess other things, so I suggest using it separately, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks, what is the difference between a callback and a promise?

Comment: Basically it simplifies the coding to avoid callback hell, check this [article](https://dev.to/tqbit/what-is-the-difference-between-callback-functions-promises-and-async-await-in-javascript-1c2k).